# android TableLayout with dynamically added cells - nothing displayed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, android-tablelayout, android-inflate

I have TableLayout with dynamically added cells. Unfortunately cells are not displayed (all dynamically added part seems to be not existing when displaying layout).

First part of my layout definition:

```
<TableLayout 
android:id="@+id/main_activity_details_calendar_main_grid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

now one cell xml definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_details_calendar_item_text_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_details_calendar_item_text_counter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now in my code I have:

```
public class MainActivity 
.....

@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

......

calendar.onCreateView(view, inflater, container);

.....

return view;
}

protected class Calendar { //this is inner class

   protected TableLayout calendarMainGrid;
   public final static int NUMBER_OF_WEEKS = 2;
   public final static int NUMBER_OF_DAYS_IN_WEEK=7;

   public void onCreateView (View view, LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {

      calendarMainGrid = (TableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.main_activity_details_calendar_main_grid);

       for (int i=0; i<=NUMBER_OF_WEEKS; i++) { //we have <= as first row will be used for displaying the names of days

          TableRow newRow = new TableRow(calendarMainGrid.getContext());
          newRow.setLayoutParams (new TableRow.LayoutParams(android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

          for (int j=0; j<NUMBER_OF_DAYS_IN_WEEK; j++) {
              View cell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_activity_details_calendar_item, container, false);

               TextView t1 = (TextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.main_activity_details_calendar_item_text_date);
           TextView t2 = (TextView) cell.findViewById(R.id.main_activity_details_calendar_item_text_counter);
           t1.setText(i*NUMBER_OF_DAYS_IN_WEEK+j);
           t2.setText(i*NUMBER_OF_DAYS_IN_WEEK+j);
               newRow.addView(cell);


    }

       calendarMainGrid.addView(newRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                        android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }
        }
```

And as I said nothing from TableLayout is displayed (other statically set elements in xml file of the same layout are correctly displayed).

Moreover LogCat displays the following warnings:

```
01-29 22:03:31.599: W/ResourceType(8561): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
```

and next warnings for numbers until 14.

I would be grateful for help. Thank you in advance!

Btw, I really don't understand why Android doesn't provide any calendar ready from the shelf with customized view on one cell..... Now instead of adding customized calendar in 5 minutes, I'm spending hours in creating calendar view from tablelayout (and I've also discovered that in my case I'm not allowed to use GridView as I've already have one ScrollView in my Layout).

Comment: When I replace the "j" loop "for (int j=0; j<NU...." with the views fully created in code, the elements are displayed. Thus I believe something is wrong in the "j" loop - either with inflating the view either with finding text views.

Answer (score 0):

> `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

try changing this to:
`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: Please explain how this solution fixes the problem at hand so that future visitors to this question can better understand.

Comment: No man, it doesn't change anything. Moreover the LogCat warning suggest that the problem is somehow related with ressources.

Comment: that was a long shot of what i

Comment: i thought that maybe because it was built dynamically it still does not obtain it parent and thus the match_parent can cause an 0 width.... i can see i was wrong it was a long shot while driving. sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Two errors:

It should be:

```
View cell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_activity_details_calendar_item, null);
```

and next:

```
t1.setText(Integer.toString(i*NUMBER_OF_DAYS_IN_ONE_WEEK+j));
```

Otherwise there is not automatic conversion as there is also setText with int parameter which means in this case ressource id.

Oh, and I spent so much time on those "stupid" bugs....

Thus the problem is solved!